# Higher order function Javascript

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

I am new to Javascript, and sturdying about the concept of higher order function, and using function as parameters.

I got two examples of code from online, and I do not understand what is going to happen.

First one, output will be 0, and I could not print the time of t1 and t2 ( I tried console.log(t1), but it became reference error). I wonder why it became 0. 
Also, I don't get how funcParameter() that is inside of functionbody is working for the function, though I know funcparameter() is callback function, and which is addOneToOne().

Second one, output will be 3. but how can it be 3 even though, I haven't put parameter into addTwo()? If I have not put anything in parameter, num will be automatically 0 or undefined?

I am sorry for many questions, but I really appreciate if you could help me out.

```js
//1st code
const timeFuncRuntime = funcParameter => {
   let t1 = Date.now();//
   funcParameter();
   let t2 = Date.now();//
   return t2 - t1;
}

const addOneToOne = () => 1 + 1;

timeFuncRuntime(addOneToOne);

console.log(timeFuncRuntime(addOneToOne))//0


//2nd code

  const addTwo = num => num + 2;


  const checkConsistentOutput = (func,   val) => {
    let firsttry = func(val);
    let secondtry = func(val);
    if(firsttry === secondtry){
      return firsttry;
    } else {
      return 'This function returned    inconsistent results';
    }
  };

  checkConsistentOutput(addTwo,1)

  console.log(checkConsistentOutput(addTwo,1))//3
```

Answer (score 1):

1: The scope of the `t1` variable is limited to the function block. You can read more about variables scope [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope)

2: You are using `val` as function parameter, and the value of `val` is 1.

> 1 + 2 = 3

The `1` is in this line:

```
checkConsistentOutput(addTwo,1)
```

Comment: I totally missed about scope! Thank you so much Cristian!

Answer (score 1):

> First one, output will be 0, and I could not print the time of t1 and t2 ( I tried console.log(t1), but it became reference error). I wonder why it became 0.

Because zero milliseconds passed between the first call to the callback and the second. `Date.now()` works in milliseconds. The call probably took microseconds at most.

You couldn't access `t1` or `t2` because they're local variables in the `timeFuncRuntime` function, so you can't access those variables outside the `timeFuncRuntime` function, only inside it.

> Also, I don't get how funcParameter() that is inside of functionbody is working for the function, though I know funcparameter() is callback function, and which is addOneToOne().

Functions are objects in JavaScript. When you do `timeFuncRuntime(addOneToOne)`, you're passing a reference to the function into `timeFuncRuntime` which it receives as the value of the `funcParameter` parameter. So when that code does `funcParameter()`, it's calling `addOneToOne`.

> Second one, output will be 3. but how can it be 3 even though, I haven't put parameter into addTwo()?

Because `checkConsistentOutput` did it. When you do `console.log(checkConsistentOutput(addTwo,1))`, you're passing a reference to `addTwo` and the number `1` into `checkConsistentOutput`. It receives them as its `func` and `val` parameters. So when it does `func(val)`, it's calling `addTwo` with the value `1`. It gets the result in the `firsttry` variable, then does the call again and gets the result in `secondtry`, and since they match, it returns the value of `firsttry`, which is `3`.

Comment: Hi, T.J. Your explanation is easier to understand, and I understand the problem, thank you so much!

just one thing, can you explain me why output will be 0 in first code? I tried console.log with t1 and t2 inside of the function and found out they have different number. Then why it ends up as 0? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @NagisaAndo - If `t1` and `t2` had different values, it wouldn't be `0`. So they must have the same value. (Which makes sense, because that call will take almost no time to run at all.)

Comment: Yes indeed! Thank you for your help again!

Answer (score 0):

> Second one, output will be 3. but how can it be 3 even though, I haven't put parameter into addTwo()?

You copy the function stored in `addTwo` as the first argument to `checkConsistentOutput` where it gets assigned to `func`. Then you call the function here — `let firsttry = func(val);` — and here — `let secondtry = func(val);`